# multilabel face filter opencv and python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

code is base on [this github link](https://github.com/kunalgupta777/OpenCV-Face-Filters)

I want put a different musk on each face detected,  I tried many ways didn't work out correctly  and  the code often  show me a out of bounds error. how to fix that

i made the filter doing the auto change by make the file path a variable  and randomly changing it when face number change. but all face will use  a same filter.  I assume I need store some kind variable ...

Comment: "I tried many ways", this is not enough, tell the details.

Comment: # I change all png file name to int, than use random function to auto load different picture
pickpicture1 = str(face01)+'.png'
face1 = cv2.imread(pickpicture1)                  
---------
numface = len(faces)
      
        if  i < numface and d != numface :
            i = i +1
            print("times loop",i)
            face01 = randint(1,12)